# GPA number to GPA letter program. Not sure why it doesn't work

Tags: java, if-statement

```
package gpatogradecalculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GPAtoGradeCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        double GPA = 0.0;

        Scanner response = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter your GPA: ");

        GPA = response.nextDouble();

        if(GPA >= 3.5); {
            System.out.println("Your GPA is an A.");


    }   else if(3.0<=GPA && GPA<3.5); {
            System.out.println("Your GPA is a B.");


    }   else if(2.5<=GPA && GPA <3.0); {
            System.out.println("Your GPA is a C.");

    }
        if(GPA < 2.5); {
            System.out.println("You are failing.");
    }

      } // end main

} // end class
```

Can anyone tell me why this wouldn't work? I don't even know where to begin to fix it.  It says that my else lines are without an if, but the if is right above them...

Comment: Hopefully you realize you can simplify the last 3 if statements to test just the first condition. Since these are else clauses, you've already checked if it's a higher grade.

Comment: you don't need semicolon after `if()`. Also the last if ( > 2.5) should be `else if`. Also the title is bad it should be the name of the error this has nothing to do with GPA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of all  `;` after `if ()`  or better sense conditional statement

for example :

```
if(GPA < 2.5); {
        System.out.println("You are failing.");
}
```

change to

```
if(GPA < 2.5) {
        System.out.println("You are failing.");
}
```

do the same process for other if statement as well

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It worked perfectly! Is there a way to quickly loop the program so that the end-user can input more than once? What I want it to do is ask for their first input, give feedback, then ask if they want to enter another input.  If they dont then the program ends, but if they do it asks for another input. Possible?

Comment: yes it is , please ask another question so we can talk about it in detail

Comment: I can't ask another question for 90 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon in `if(GPA >= 3.5); {` and similar if statements.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `;` after conditional statement.

Comment: give you vote up for mentioning conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

Don't put semicolons after each if.